# How to close child and all step child windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that tracks work time. Very basic. I have a button on the main winform that says Reports. When the Reports dialog is opened there is a set of buttons that open other dialog boxes for action to be taken.

I'm trying to exit the Reports dialog and close all child windows at the same time. If the Reports dialog is closed, all child windows of the Reports dialog should close but the time tracking should remain open. I believe these are modeless windows. I can interact with all dialogs without closing parent dialogs.

```
    private void StartForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start f1 = new Start();
        f1.Owner = this;
        f1.Show();
    }
```

So basically I have:

MainForm > ChildForm > ManyStepChildren(??) This is how I've tried to close the child and stepchildren

```
    private void Close_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose(); //did not work
        this.Exit(); //Crashed the entire application

    }
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your ChildForm should keep track of opened "StepChildren". When closing ChildForm, first command all "StepChildren" to close first, and only close ChildForm after that.

Comment: Just a stupid remark, but don't you mean grandchildren? :)

Comment: @Silvermind Ok. Yes. Grandchildren. :-D

Comment: What do you mean by *...but the time tracking should remain open.*?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε  I don't want to close the application. I only want to close the child window and any Grandchildren/stepchildren. The application needs to continue running for the purpose of tracking work time.

Comment: If you close the child window all the  Grandchildren/stepchildren will close automatically. *this.Close();* is enough.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Unfortunately it does not. It only closes the first child window. The grandchildren/stepchildren do not close and they are still visible in TaskManager. I assume that means the thread is still active in memory or running. Forgive me Please. I'm not even a beginner geek :-) Just a Newb.

Comment: You must create the *grandchildren/stepchildren* the same way as in *StartForm_Click()*

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε Thank you very much for your help. It's asking me to move to chat?? Not sure what that is. StartForm_Click() is called on the MainForm. Do I have to call all of the Grandchildren forms through the MainForm and then pass them to my Reports form??

Comment: No. Every time you create a form set its owner the same way you did it for the child.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε PHUCHING BRILLIANT :-D :-D

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I don't know how important the forum prestige?? is to you, but I can't thumbs up your comment. Can you post an answer and I'll do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε

Brilliant answer. Thank You. I'm will definitely be reading more about .Owner  I can see this becoming very powerful to use.

Per @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε the answer was to give ownership of the Grandchildren dialog boxes to Reports

```
    private void bSubmitTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TrackChildForm();

        SubmitTime sf1 = new SubmitTime();
        sf1.Owner = this;
        sf1.Show();
    }
```

Then when exiting to just .Close(). I chose .Dispose() as I've been told this will clean up the system a little more. Trying to code cleanly. :-D

```
    private void Close_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 p = (Form1)this.Owner;
        Control[] c = p.Controls.Find("bStartForm", true);
        Button b = (Button)c[0];
        b.Enabled = true;

        this.Dispose(); 

    }
```

Thank you to all for responding. I really appreciate it. Have a Great Day!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating all child windows from `Report` window to show right? Why don't you keep `List` of those child windows, and on `Report` window's close event, iterate thru all of child windows and close them all?
Let's say this is your ChildForm

```
public class ChildForm: Form/Window
{
   private IList<Form/Window> _childWindows = new List<Form/Window>();

   private void ButtonClickTahWillOpenSomeChild(....)
   {
      var childWindow = new ChildWindow();
      // you might want to check if it already exists before adding in case someone clicks button twice
      _childWindows.Add(childWindow);
     // your code
   }

  // other click handlers that will open another child windows
  private void ChildForm_Close(...)
  {
      foreach(var window in _childWindows)
      {
         window.Close();
      }
      // rest of your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is definitely tracking the forms that are being opened. Thank you for getting me this far. I appreciate it. The forms are not being closed though. Wait wait.

Comment: This was great for tracking, but it didn't close the windows. Gives me a great idea for placing the form name in memory for reading from though. :-) Thanks @michael-moore